# Examples of a Manifest

Tags: manifest

I have a problem with a legacy (almost historic!) application which has stopped working because it can no longer locate a dll installed in the application folder.  I suspect this is caused by Windows 11 COM changes as previously it was found using an application.exe.local.  I believe I now need a manifest for this but I have no idea how to format one and so far online documentation has been less than helpful.
I'm looking for a manifest example, and/or advice on what its contents should be.  I think that all it needs to do is point Windows at the .dll sitting beside it in the app folder but to not interfere with other dll's and OCX's it uses in (say) SysWoW64.

I have tried Microsoft manifest explanations but to be honest I don't understand them.